# How to install FFMPEG encoders on Linux CentOS 5 Server

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg

I need to install

- LAME MP3 Encoder
- Libogg + Libvorbis
- Mencoder and also Mplayer
- FFMpeg-PHP

For a script called PHPmotion. I do have root access so please does anyone have a step by step. I am fairly comfortable with linux commands, but I am not a pro by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our internal wiki page at work on doing this references http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/03/03/installing-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php-mplayer-mencoder-flv2tool-lame-mp3-encoder-libogg-–-the-easy-way/ (you'll have to fix up the URL manually, I have NFI what they've put in the middle of it) -- I haven't tried it myself, and the page is looking a bit old now, but it should at least get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [rpmforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) release for RHEL (CentOS) 5.

```
rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Then install ffmpeg package

```
yum -y install ffmpeg
```

The rest of the packages should also be in the rpmforge release.

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally need media/codecs stuff for my Centos boxes, but I definitely do on my Fedora desktops.  For the latter case, I get them from [RPMFusion](http://rpmfusion.org), which just happens to have repositories for RHEL5-compatible releases so I would suggest looking there first.

Answer (score 0):

The automated installer over @ http://ffmpeginstaller.com/ will have everything you need. Although if you don't have root access that would be an issue. Try and bubble this up to your host, should be an easy addition for them as long as you're not on shared hosting. I'd imagine PHPMotion will be utilizing shell_exec as well to execute ffmpeg commands so be sure to clarify that with them as well.